# $\frac{\partial ^3z}{\partial x^3}-4\frac{\partial^3z}{\partial x ^2\partial y}+4\frac{\partial ^3 z}{\partial x \partial y^2}=2sin(3x+2y)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

$$\frac{\partial ^3z}{\partial x^3}-4\frac{\partial^3z}{\partial x ^2\partial y}+4\frac{\partial ^3 z}{\partial x \partial y^2}=2sin(3x+2y)$$

What is wrong with my solution?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It'll be better if, instead of posting photos, you write down your solution using mathjax!

Comment: @DavideMorgante Sir, actually these are long questions and it takes a lot of time to type them in mathjax.

Comment: Yes, I know it can be tedious! Just look at my answers how long and involved they can be. It was only a suggestion: people here reward OP's if they follow the basic guidelines of this site! https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Answer (score 2):

Our solution is corect.
With  free CAS Maxima:

[image]